# For an explicit mapping $S^m\to S^6$ for $m<12$, how can we understand whether it is homotopy zero?

Tags: homotopy-theory, geometric-topology, higher-homotopy-groups

In my work I have mappings from $S^m$ to $S^6$, where $m\leq 11$. People know the homotopy group of these mappings. However, is there some algorithm that helps to recognize when mappings (we can assume that the mappings are simplicial) are homotopic to each other? I would be grateful for links.

Comment: Elements of $\pi_6(S^6)$ and $\pi_{11}(S^6)$ are classified by the degree and Hopf invariant. These are in principle easy to compute using (co)homology or topological K-theory. In other degrees the homotopy groups are either $\mathbb{Z}/2$ or zero, except for $m=9$, so this should in principle also be easy. It's hard to say without knowing the maps you are dealing with.